# How do you get the network symbol in Python+web3?

Tags: python, web3py

I can get a token's symbol using: tokenContract.functions.symbol().call()
But how do I get the symbol for the current network?
Use case:

```
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(init.differentNetwork))
walletBalanceTmp = web3.eth.getBalance(init.walletAddress)
walletBalance = web3.fromWei(walletBalanceTmp, 'ether')
print(f"Current wallet balance: {walletBalance} network token")
```

Output:

Current wallet balance: 5.3 network token

How can I replace "network token" with "BSC" or "MATIC", depending on my init.differentNetwork infura id.

Answer (score 0):

See this [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/98000) from the Ethereum Stack Exchange site.

You should use a pre-set database (https://chainid.network/chains.json) for mapping the current chainId.